# How to sum N columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a pandas df and I'd like to sum N of the columns. The df might look like this:

```
A B C D ... X

1 4 2 6     3
2 3 1 2     2 
3 1 1 2     4
4 2 3 5 ... 1
```

I'd like to get a df like this:

```
A Z

1 15
2 8
3 8
4 11
```

The A variable is not an index, but a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for new `Series` created by `sum` all columns without `A`:

```
df = df[['A']].join(df.drop('A', 1).sum(axis=1).rename('Z'))
```

Or extract column `A` first by [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df = df.pop('A').to_frame().join(df.sum(axis=1).rename('Z'))
```

If want select columns by positions use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[:, [0]].join(df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1).rename('Z'))
```

---

```
print (df)
   A   Z
0  1  15
1  2   8
2  3   8
3  4  11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` column

```
df.groupby(['A']+['Z']*(df.shape[1]-1),axis=1).sum()
Out[252]: 
   A   Z
0  1  15
1  2   8
2  3   8
3  4  11
```